# unix command - size of directory with order by size

Tags: sorting, unix, du

I use this command:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -s
```

And my result is:

```
1.1M    ./abcd
1.1M    ./efgh
1.1M    ./xyxabcd
1.2G    ./oleoleole
1.2M    ./tests
196K    ./super-Package
2.0M    ./myjobs-build
```

However, I want it to be ordered by size like this:

```
1.2G    ./oleoleole
2.0M    ./myjobs-build
1.2M    ./tests
1.1M    ./abcd
1.1M    ./efgh
1.1M    ./xyxabcd
196K    ./super-Package
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr`

Comment: This was answered 2 hours ago by another user. I don't understand why this is the one accepted, apart from the fact that asked and answerer are from the same city.

Comment: I validated this response because it corresond exactly what I needed. Other responses were too wordy for my simple needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
du -sh * | sort -hr
```

Here -h flag tells the operating system to sort that the input is the human-readable format

Here -r flag tells to sort in descending order

**Sample Output:**

```
Sai Kiran@Windows MINGW32 /bin
$ du -sh * | sort -hr
3.5M    msys-2.0.dll
2.3M    vimdiff.exe
2.3M    vim.exe
2.3M    view.exe
2.3M    rvim.exe
2.3M    rview.exe
2.3M    ex.exe
2.1M    sh.exe
2.1M    bash.exe
2.0M    msys-crypto-1.0.0.dll
1.9M    msys-perl5_22.dll
1.1M    sed.exe
932K    gpg.exe
928K    msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll
912K    msys-iconv-2.dll
816K    msys-sqlite3-0.dll
760K    winpty-agent.exe
756K    sshd.exe
712K    winpty.dll
704K    msys-svn_wc-1-0.dll
700K    ssh.exe
700K    slogin.exe
628K    rebase.exe
588K    openssl.exe
568K    gawk-4.1.3.exe
568K    gawk.exe
568K    awk.exe
557K    core_perl
544K    msys-asn1-8.dll
508K    msys-gmp-10.dll
472K    winpty.exe
472K    msys-curl-4.dll
452K    msys-krb5-26.dll
432K    ssh-keyscan.exe
432K    cygcheck.exe
428K    msys-svn_client-1-0.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print `du` in bytes, sort and post-process the data with `awk`:

```
du --max-depth=1 |
   sort -n -k1 | 
   awk -v u="K M G T" 'BEGIN{split(u, units);}
   { while($1 > 1024) {$1/=1024; unit++} $1=$1 FS units[unit]; unit=0 }
   1'
```

#### Test

```
$ mkdir a{1..3}
$ seq 100000 > a1/a
$ seq 100000000 > a2/a
$ seq 100 > a3/a
```

So that we have:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
580K    ./a1
8,0K    ./a3
848M    ./a2
849M    .
```

And now we see:

```
$ du --max-depth=1 | sort -n -k1 | awk -v u="K M G T" 'BEGIN{split(u, units);} { while($1 > 1024) {$1/=1024; unit++} $1=$1 units[unit]; unit=0 }1'
8 ./a3
580 ./a1
847.719K ./a2
848.297K .
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` command will only sort the lines of an output file as stated in its man page:

> sort - sort lines of text files

When you want to sort files by size you can simply use `ls` command with `-S` switch:

> -s, --size
>                 print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
>
> -S     sort by file size, largest first

[link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ls-command-sort-by-file-size/)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below one-liner bash shell script for listing all the files recusrively with size of files of multiple folders.
Note: Kindly change folder location according to your demand.

```
/usr/bin/du -a /var/log /home/user/log |sort -nr |awk '{print $NF}'|while read l ;do echo "file $(du -csh $l|grep -vi total) " ;done|nl
```